# Are nexted loops possible in this form?

Tags: vba, excel

I've spent a couple days trying to work this one out. What i'm trying to do is take a date (Current_date) and compare it to a list (around 150 values, GRD dates), this should then return the number the current date is greater than. This should then be printed. Once this is done the current date moves to the next date and the whole process repeats.

```
Sub GRD()

Dim Current_date As Long
Dim GRD_Count As Long
Dim Count As Long
Dim g As Long
Dim GRD_end_date As Long

GRD_Count = 0
Count = 10
g = 10

Do Until Worksheets("ABC").Cells(Count, 14).Value = ""

    Current_date = Worksheets("ABC").Cells(Count, 14).Value

        Do Until Worksheets("ABC").Cells(g, 3).Value = ""

            GRD_end_date = Worksheets("ABC").Cells(g, 9).Value

                If Current_date > GRD_end_date Then
                    GRD_Count = GRD_Count + 1

                Else: GRD_Count = GRD_Count

                End If


            g = g + 1


        Loop

    Worksheets("ABC").Cells(Count, 16).Value = GRD_Count
    Count = Count + 1
Loop



End Sub
```

It is giveing me values of 1 for all dates, even though this should be the value for the first Current_date only.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: not sure yet, but what is a GRD date? is it a type of gregorian calender? and why are you storing dates in longs? maybe use Cdate and store them in date variable - that would make equallity operator more accurate i think.
also i'm not sure what's your GRD_count stands for, is it a counter for how much GRD dates you passed for current date? or is it a global that represent something else? if it's the first, then you need to re-init it every loop

Comment: Avishay, GRD_Date is a date on the sheet I am referring too. Nothing special. I have a list of around 150 of these dates. I have changed the date variables to As Date as you suggested. GRD_count refers to the number of GRD_Dates that are before Current_date. I run current date against all these GRD dates and print a number (GRD_Count). Then I move to the next Current_Date, rest GRD count and repeat. I hop that helps.

Comment: from what i'm seeing you don't reset the GRD_count each iteration, you init it before starting to loop, and inside the loops, you either increment it by 1, when curr_date > GRD_end_date, or keep it the same otherwise (which is redundent but nevermind now). try adding a GRD_count = 0 after printing it before you loop back to the next row.

Comment: ahh I've fixed it. I can't believe I missed that. I needed to reset the GRD count and also the g value.

Comment: you're welcome, that's what the site is for. have a nice day.

Comment: @AvishayCohen or lordf, can you post an answer and accept?  Helps those of us looking for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i'm seeing you don't reset the GRD_count each iteration, you init it before starting to loop, and inside the loops, you either increment it by 1, when curr_date > GRD_end_date, or keep it the same otherwise (which is redundent but nevermind now). try adding a GRD_count = 0 after printing it before you loop back to the next row.